# Crystal Reports not show numbers just blank field from XLS data source

Tags: crystal-reports

I try to make a CR report from excel file. But the number fields are blank in CR (Like 97007244). If i put the cell one letter (Like X97007244), CR shows the field.

I tried to change cell type to text, but still not show.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The report probably assigned incorrect data type to that column.

Try to do ***Database, Verify Database...***